# What does "They found themselves standing on a platform" mean?

Tags: expressions

There is some argument over on [german.stackexchange.com](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/76342/57303). Many users there believe that the sentence is ambiguous.

My opinion is that this sentence would be used to describe how someone unexpectedly comes to a place, looks around, and realizes where they are.

Other opinions are that "to find oneself" (in the context of the example sentence!) could mean "just be there", "get into something", "catch oneself doing something", "to bring oneself to do sth", "to unexpectedly or unintentionally begin to do or experience something" and so on.

What do *native speakers* understand that sentence to mean?

Comment: What is the wider context? Your opinion is the most likely (but not _only_) interpretation without any other information.

Comment: [find oneself](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/find%20oneself) has an idiomatic meaning, but it probably doesn't apply here. Most of the definitions you give refer to the same meaning: unexpectedly finding yourself in a place, unexpectedly experience something, and "catch yourself doing something" mean the same thing, so maybe you could explain in more detail why there was any argument.

Comment: @KillingTime To my surprise, ["they found themselves standing on a platform"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22They+found+themselves+standing+on+a+platform.%22&filter=0#ip=1) seems to have been used at least ten different times.  They all seem to suggest the same sense of discovering that they were somewhere, though not always the same sense of platform.

Comment: @Henry How weird. Perhaps AI is already finishing off writing. Geesus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common understanding of this would be that they unexpectedly discovered they were standing on a platform. This could be because they walked through a door, or woke up there, or were  miraculously transported there, or many other reasons.

The only other  interpretation I can think of is that they "found themselves" (realized their true metaphysical nature) while they were standing on a platform. There may be others I haven't thought of.  It's a bit unlikely and the first interpretation is by far the most common.

Comment: Yes, right but platform could be replaced by a ton of other places.

Comment: Yes, certainly.

Answer (score 1):

They found themselves + prepositional phrase -> They became aware that they were + prepositional phrase.

They found themselves on a platform -> They became aware that they were on a platform.

They found themselves + adjectival -> they became aware + content clause

They found themselves unable to move -> They became aware that they were unable to move.

> [**MW:** find (v)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/find)
>
> 3b: **to perceive (oneself) to be in a certain place or condition**
>
> found himself in prison awaiting deportation
>
> found himself on the verge of bankruptcy

Comment: MW doesn't include the sudden or gradual realisation aspect in its definition that you correctly do in yours. I'd say there's some level of surprise, too.

Answer (score 0):

It means they tuned back in from whatever had been distracting them and realized they were now standing on the platform. Perhaps two people had been lost in conversation while they walked to the station, and only just realized they had arrived. And it's a rhetorical device that gives the reader a chance to catch up with a new situation. It has the effect of focusing one on the location content.

It is not ambiguous to those familiar with the idiom. I doesn't mean *they found themselves*, and happened to be on a platform.

Comment: “Tuned back”? Is it really good practice to use slang to explain an expression, especially to a non-native speaker?

Comment: @David I don't think that "tune in" is slang, either in Cambridge or MW.

Comment: @Lambie — It is a contemporary idiomatic expression, probably dating from the 1960s (guess, but my mother wouldn't have understood it) and be unlikely to be encountered in a language course. Using one idiom to explain another is still not a good way of teaching imho.

Comment: @David Well, I purposely chose it because it was an idiom, so we differ on that point, I think it is good to explain one idiom with another when it preserves the overall feel of the statement. Ludwig has examples of *tune back in* from the NYT and The New Yorker

Comment: This is a medical definition from a VA website- Mindfulness is being fully aware and tuned in to what is going on in the present moment. It takes time to cultivate, but with practice, it comes naturally.

Comment: Aaargh… The M-word! I surrender.